# Nginx не передает X-Real-IP apache

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, apache2.4

Использую связку nginx + apache2.4 + ubuntu 14.04.

Мне необходимо закрыть доступ по ip через .htacces.(который лежит на Apache).

Поэтому необходимо, что бы Nginx передал ip пользователя Apache через $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], но получается его передать только в $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'].

Кто нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Конфиг nginx такой:

```
    server { 
server_name site.test146.ru site2.test146.ru;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
location / {
proxy_pass http://5.23.48.116:8080/;
set_real_ip_from  5.23.48.116;
real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
real_ip_recursive on;
proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_connect_timeout 120;
proxy_send_timeout 120;
proxy_read_timeout 180;
proxy_buffering off;
client_max_body_size 10m;
}
}
    listen 443 ssl; 
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.test146.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.test146.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = site.test146.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 
listen 5.23.48.116:80;
server_name site.test146.ru;
    return 404; 
}
```

Comment: Ищите в апаче аналог real_ip_header.

Comment: Гугл подсказывает, что это mod_remoteip

Answer (score 0):

Получилось решить задачу, благодаря mod_remoteip.

Пользовался этим гайдом: http://rudenko.net.ua/zamena_modulu_mod_rpaf_v_apache_24/

Единственное, что пошло не по гайду - вместо правки конфига  /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, правил /etc/nginx/site-available/default